# Baked Texture is Darker and uglier than the render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm new in blender and searching for the answer of my problem anywhere but I got nothing
heres my problem, when im bake the object, the result seem ugly, darker, and dissapointing. dosnt even close with my render, here the screenshot

[image: the render view]
and here when i put the image texture and see it in the material viewport (it should look same with the render view)

[image: the baked texture in the floor seem dissapointing, different from the render]

and here when I put the baked texture wall in unity

[image: baked wall texture that I put in unity]

what did I do wrong guys?? ty for your respond
(sry english is not my first language).

Answer (score -1):

I think you did it right, but rendering is not the same as the viewport material preview. If your baking and your textures are large enough (not to loose detail because of that) increase the sample rate. Baking will take a while then too (maybe a hour or longer). Try a sample rate first double current then try 400 or 1000

PS perhaps you should take a look what 2.8 eevee can do for your kind of work.

Comment: hmm, but when I see this blender guru tutorial, the material  view should be the same with the render view when we put the baked texture into an object.. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU)

and Im alredy put the sample to 500
and i dont know about the eevee though, i need to export it to UNITY for my game

Comment: Hm note that baking is usually done for static scenario's ea architecture where later wont be ligths and shadows (no moving game characters), or you get a shadow over shadow effect., for smaller objects baking is done as well (to bake bump textures),.. i'm not into unity, i thought you where learning for architectural work. Eventually when baked render finishes all materialls are replaced by the backed version (it should be better include better shadows)
But my advice might then not apply to your gaming requirements (sorry).

Comment: no problem, im really apreciate you came to help me :D